# wcf autofac integration hanging in ServiceChannelFactory.ChannelCreated

Tags: wcf, autofac

We have an MVC application using downstream web services via wcf.
We followed the [proposed approach](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WcfIntegration) of registering a singleton ChannelFactory, which will create a channel InstancePerDependency (if I am not mistaken).

We observe the following issues in production:

- Profiling shows that an inordinate amount of time is spent in [System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/ServiceChannelFactory.cs).ChannelCreated (few 100ms, occasionally multiple seconds). The only thing that can take any significant time in that method is acquiring a lock.
- Performance counters show linear increase in CLR > Lock and Thread > Contention Rate / sec over time.

I suspect that somehow channels are not properly disposed. The ChannelFactory keeps a list of all channels (OnCreated adds the new Channel to the list, after acquiring the lock). When a channel is closed, or Aborted it gets removed from the list, after acquiring the lock. If the list becomes huge the removal can take long, and OnCreated has to wait for the lock.

We have the autofac resolved IService injected in Controller methods, and in some instances also use DependecyResolver.Current.GetService. My understanding was that the autofac WCF integration would take care of the disposal. Is that not so? What's the proper way to ensure Channel disposal?

Answer (score 0):

The suspicion voiced in the question turned out to be true, channels were leaking.
There were two issues with the application at hand:

1. the IService dependency resolution was registered with default perDependency instance scope, resulting in a ton of channels being created. In a web application you probably want to use the perHttpRequest scope for wcf client channel resolution. (this alone should not have resulted in a leak though)
2. In Global.Application_Start a global filter resolved via autofac was registerd. The constructor of that filter class took a func<IDependency> as a constructor argument and some sub dependency of it had a dependency on IService. The func was only evaluated from within a web request, but it appears the lifetime scope of all dependencies resolved during func evaluation was that the func was resolved in, i.e. the application. (Not 100% certain on this. But if the perHttpRequest instance scope is requested for the IService resolution, one instance, for the app lifetime, is created according to the resolution in the global filter, and never disposed, and another is created for each httpRequest, and properly disposed at the end of the request)